# Better Xamarin Android debugging experience?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

While i am doing debugging  for a xamarin Forms application and  i run the Android program in the emulator , once an error happens the visual studio does not break at the line  where the problem happens , just opens a new page showing the error . 
Is there a way to improve the Xamarin Android debugging a bit ?

Comment: You could still see the error message log in the Output window.

Comment: but doesn't break at the line where the error happened like Xamarin UWP thats a big deal

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems that surrounding the code blocks all around the application  with try catch will get the desired effect . Place the breakpoint inside all the catch blocks and one of them will trigger .